# How to tile this texture with Geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, texture-coordinates

I'm trying to create a texture that can be wrapped around a simple cylinder but I need the parametric qualities afforded by geo nodes to be able to adjust the pattern for 3D printing/ prototyping purposes. The texture needs to simulate some gentle waves you might see across the surface of a pond on a quiet day so I was hoping to have 2 "waves" interacting across the surface. This texture also needs to be able to tile on one axis so it can wrap around the side of the cylinder and be seamless.

[image]

I'm new to geo nodes so any help is appreciated.

[image: Geo nodes wave setup]

this is the blend file:

[image]

Comment: a picture would help how it should look like

Comment: Hi, troysin, welcome to BSE ... Please add a picture of the progress, and share on https://blend-exchange.com/ , rather than via a private link. I would edit your question myself, but because of the link as it stands, feel I need your permission.

Comment: @RobinBetts feel free to edit it!

Comment: @Chris something like this - more the bottom half of the image than the top


 https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.deviantart.com%2Ffantasystock%2Fart%2FPond-Water-Texture-126901590&psig=AOvVaw3aCuwTm_CTnUGgAOw9-NFb&ust=1686873026359000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CBEQjRxqFwoTCLCkwe75w_8CFQAAAAAdAAAAABAE